# Reassigning prototypes of build-in types

Tags: javascript, oop, object, prototype

```
Number.prototype=
{  
    constructor:Number
    min:10,
    max:15
};
var obj=new Number();
alert(obj.min);
```

Here I have created a new prototype for the default `Number` constructor.
Then a new instance of `Number` is created and stored in `obj`.
As I have created an instance after the prototype assignment I expect that `obj.min` will return `10` but it's returning `undefined`.

I assume that because the constructor property of newly created `Number.prototype` points to the same `Number` constructor then the instance `obj`'s `[PROTOTYPE]` property points to newly created  prototype.

I think the problem lies in the assumption and that the `obj`'s `[PROTOTYPE]` property points to the the original default prototype.

Comment: You forgot a comma after "Number" ;)

Comment: As per specification, `Number.prototype` is readonly: http://es5.github.io/#x15.7.3.1. @Andre: Must be a typo in the post, otherwise the `alert` would never be executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prototype property of core types defined by ECMAScript (`Object`, `Number`, `Boolean`, `Array`, `String`, `Function`, `Error`, `RegExp`) is read-only, you can't replace it with your own.

But you can extend it :

```
Number.prototype.min = 5;
```

Comment: @chetanmehta: untrue on Chrome. http://tinker.io/c3d8b . They can be extended - the browser-defined functions on them, however, cannot be replaced.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld You're not replacing the prototype in your function.

Comment: coz i dont find any mysterious prop occuring in Object.getOwnPropertyNames

Comment: @Sébastien: `readonly` means that the value cannot be changed. However the value itself (the object) can be extended.

Comment: @chetanmehta: There's only one setting that makes a property read-only. That's the `writeable` setting, and the spec clearly defines `.prototype` of `Number` as being `writeable:false`. To see it, use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Number, "prototype")`.

Comment: @dystroy: I am not replacing, I am extending. Correct me if I'm wrong, the OP does not need to replace, either. None of his properties clash with built-in `Number` properties or methods.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, since this at least explains why the OP's code is not working. However, to provide a solution as well, maybe you can add that extending the prototype is possible.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld: The question is attempting an entire replacement, and is wondering why it doesn't work. This answer explains why.